# Change values of a structured numpy array column (having column key's) depending on condition

Tags: python, numpy

I have a structured array "X2" (having column keys) that looks like:

`print(X2)`

```
 LSTAT  target
0     4.98    24.0
1     9.14    21.6
2     4.03    34.7
3     2.94    33.4
4     5.33    36.2
..     ...     ...
501   9.67    22.4
502   9.08    20.6
503   5.64    23.9
504   6.48    22.0
505   7.88    11.9
```

I now would like to change the column target to 0. if the actual value is lower than a variable's value (variable median_tar), otherwise to 1.

How can I update the array by this condition?

I tried the following

```
for xtar in np.nditer(X2.target, op_flags=['readwrite']):
        if xtar < median_tar:
            xtar = 0.
            print(xtar)
        else:
            xtar = 1.
            print(xtar)
np.nditer.close
```

print(xtar) prints the correct results, but the values of array X2 in the column target does not change at all.

What's wrong here, and how to do better?

Thank you for your support.

Comment: `nditer` is tricky to use if you don't read its docs and examples thoroughly

Comment: The display looks more like a `pandas` dataframe than a `numpy` structured array.  Though the fact that you can use `X2.target` suggests it could be a `recarray`.  But even that doesn't display in a table format.

Comment: Generally we don't encourage the use of `nditer`, unless you intend to move on to coding in `cython`.  But here using `xtar=0` has the problem with all Python iterations - it changes the `xtar` locally, but not in the source `X2.target`.  `xtar[...]=0` might make this work, since it modifies the `xtar` object, rather than assign a new value to the variable.  Hopefully `nditer` documentation makes that clear.

Answer (score 0):

Not really clear but if X2 is a 2d numpy array follow this:

First get the second column in the 2d array by:

```
X2[:,1]
```

With `np.where` you can add a condition and modify the column. This is what you need:

```
X2[:,1] = np.where(X2[:,1] < median_tar,0,1)
```

If X2 is a pandas DataFrame follow this:

```
X2['target'] = np.where(X2['target'] < median_tar,0,1)
```

Comment: Thank you so far ... :-)

Comment: How do I get the new values back in the target row?

Comment: Is your data a numpy array or pandas dataframe? I edited my first answer.

Answer (score 0):

Making a pandas dataframe:

```
In [244]: df=pd.DataFrame(np.arange(10).reshape(5,2),columns=['x','y'])         
In [245]: df                                                                    
Out[245]: 
   x  y
0  0  1
1  2  3
2  4  5
3  6  7
4  8  9
```

This displays like your example.  You have a dataframe, not a numpy structured array.

```
In [247]: df.x            # column access by attribute                                                                  
Out[247]: 
0    0
1    2
2    4
3    6
4    8
Name: x, dtype: int64
```

A working use of `nditer`:

```
In [248]: for xtar in np.nditer(df.x, op_flags=['readwrite']): 
     ...:     if xtar<5: 
     ...:         xtar[...]=0    # correct way of modifying xtar 
     ...:                                                                       
In [249]: df                                                                    
Out[249]: 
   x  y
0  0  1
1  0  3
2  0  5
3  6  7
4  8  9
```

While this works, it isn't the recommended of operating on a dataframe, or numpy array - unless you need some special behavior.  `np.nditer` is best seen as a stepping stone toward writing compiled numpy code.  It is not a faster iterator, at least on in Python level code.

===

We can get a `recarray` from the dataframe with:

```
In [250]: arr = df.to_records()                                                 
In [251]: arr                                                                   
Out[251]: 
rec.array([(0, 0, 1), (1, 0, 3), (2, 0, 5), (3, 6, 7), (4, 8, 9)],
          dtype=[('index', '<i8'), ('x', '<i8'), ('y', '<i8')])
```

Note the different display.

```
In [252]: arr.x                     # attribute access                                                                 
Out[252]: array([0, 0, 0, 6, 8])
In [253]: arr['x']                  # field name access (structured array style)                          
Out[253]: array([0, 0, 0, 6, 8])
```

Modification of the field with boolean masking, no looping:

```
In [254]: arr.x[arr.x==0] = 1                                                   
In [255]: arr                                                                   
Out[255]: 
rec.array([(0, 1, 1), (1, 1, 3), (2, 1, 5), (3, 6, 7), (4, 8, 9)],
          dtype=[('index', '<i8'), ('x', '<i8'), ('y', '<i8')])
```

===

Similar whole data Series modification

```
In [257]: df.x==0                                                               
Out[257]: 
0     True
1     True
2     True
3    False
4    False
Name: x, dtype: bool
In [258]: df.x[df.x==0] = 1                                                     
In [259]: df                                                                    
Out[259]: 
   x  y
0  1  1
1  1  3
2  1  5
3  6  7
4  8  9
```